Möller-Granlund Reciprocal Calculation for Arbitrary Bases
In their paper Improved division by invariant integers, Niels Möoller and Torbjörn Granlund describe an algorithm (Algorithm 2 and Algorithm 3) based on Newton-Raphson iteration to efficiently calculate a reciprocal of a (positive) integer $d$.  To be precise, for a base $\beta = 2^\ell$ and a $\beta/2 \leq d < \beta$, the reciprocal $v$ is defined to be $v = \left\lfloor\frac{\beta^2 - 1} d\right\rfloor - \beta$.  (The idea of subtracting $\beta$ is that $v$ can be represented in one word.)  The reciprocal can then be used, for example, to implement the division of a double word by a single word (which can then be used to implement a long division algorithm).
The algorithms given explicitly in the paper are (very cleverly) tailored for the case $\ell = 32$ and $\ell = 64$.  My question is whether there is a version of such an algorithm that works with arbitrary word sizes (and doesn't do unnecessary wide multiplications).
What are other known efficient algorithms to calculate the reciprocal of a normalized integer $d$ with (roughly) $\ell$ significant bits both for the input and output?
